# What is "or was she?" meaning here

Tags: meaning-in-context

Explain to me what the question "Or was she?" means, please. The text is:

> I heard the back door and froze. If anyone came my way, they might see me, so I pressed back against the window well, hoping to melt into the darkness.
>   "Where are they going?" I whispered.
>   "My way," Ashley said.
>   "Run!"
>   "Can't. Be quite."
>   It was weird standing in a window well, listening to your sister get caught. **Or was she?**

Comment: Should be 'or did she?' (or did she get caught?)

Comment: Also I think 'be quite' should be 'be quiet'.